# Is there a neutral alternative term for Brandolini's law?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

As you may know, [Brandolini’s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandolini%27s_law) states:

> The amount of energy needed to refute bullshit is an order of magnitude bigger than that needed to produce it.

I am looking for a term that shows the **asymmetry** between just making a hypothesis or claim or allegation (which is **easy** to do) and providing a proof or evidence for the claim (which is **hard** and takes a lot of energy).  If you use it strictly, Brandolini’s law is only applicable to bullshit or wrong claims but not for reasonable claims (that is, claims that may be right).

Is there a recognized term for this that covers both types of claims, meaning that they could be bullshit ***or*** really worth consideration but that the proof is always hard?

ChatGPT suggested *asymmetry of proof* and *verification asymmetry*, but neither of these is a popular or recognized term even though both make some sense. The closest thing I could find conceptually is [*burden of proof*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(philosophy)). I guess the *burden of proof* idea also comes from this asymmetry.

You can also see that making claims/hypotheses are easy from the proliferation of conspiracy theories and from the popularity of derogatory remarks like "empty theorizing". (Even though most of the time these turn out to be wrong sometimes they turn out to be true, but proving them true/false is still hard which is why I am looking for a term that is neutral, just so that the asymmetry should not be just related to nonsense claims).

Is this a recognized issue in general (so much so that it merits a term), meaning that hypotheses are cheap but proofs take work? If so, what words or concepts do philosophers, thinkers, or scientists use to address this issue?

Comment: I did ask the question on [English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/621034/is-there-a-value-neutral-word-for-brandolinis-law) and someone suggested mud-sticks but what I am looking for is a term that would cover the general idea that the effort involved in putting out a random theory (anyone can conjure up a random theory) is way higher than validating your random theory (which is way hard). It's similar to the "Talk is Cheap" idea that it is easy to hypothesize but proving something is hard.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but one might be able to argue it's an instance of entropy. It takes more effort to maintain complex structures than it does for them to eventually fall apart - perhaps similar things are true about information amongst humans. I'm not certain there's something worthwhile in this idea, but it occurred to me now so I thought I'd share it.

Comment: Beware of status quo bias though. When someone introduces a new idea, it's probably *not* completely random, even if it seems that way to you; they likely have some reasons for thinking it's worthwhile that you don't know until you listen to what they have to say.

Comment: And every established idea was at one time new and untested. If we are interested in pursuing truth, we need to have an affinity for novelty. Even if 99% of novel ideas fail, we should not be discouraged, because it is only by sifting through these that we might identify the 1% of new ideas that are really good.

Comment: "*Talk is cheap, until you talk with a Lawyer*"

Comment: @causative Totally agree with you, most of the time these hypotheses turn out to be false but sometimes they turn out to be true, but that doesn't make proving them true/false any different, it's still hard, which is exactly why I am looking for a term that is neutral, just so that the asymmetry should not be just related to nonsense claims but to all hypotheses right and wrong.